# Storing the number of template arguments of a variadic template

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

In the following example

```
template <size_t... Entries>
struct StaticArray
{
  enum {N = sizeof...(Entries)};
  size_t array[N] = {Entries...};
};
```

storing the number of Entries in an `enum` seems more like a hack to me.

Is this really the text-book way of storing the number of Entries or is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: "Storing" is an odd way to put it. No storage is used, and C++ templates are all declarations. So `N` is more of an alias than anything else. Having said that, I agree with @Barry's answer: `enum` is not the best mechanism.

Comment: "enum hack" was literally the common name of this, so that should tell you something :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would prefer a `static constexpr` member:

```
template <size_t... Entries>
struct StaticArray
{
    static constexpr size_t N = sizeof...(Entries);
    size_t array[N] = {Entries...};
};
```

Possibly with a bunch of other `constexpr` member functions (`size()`, `begin()`, `end()`, `data()`, etc.)

Comment: +1, the `enum` hack is not necessary anymore, now that we have `constexpr` (and to be honest, possibly before that in many practical situations). as long as your program doesn't take the address of a `constexpr`, it will be inlined as a literal (by any half-decent compiler, yadda yadda).